# Error while calculating last row of adjucent column

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code in VBA to fill down formula in cell Y3:AB3 till the last row of column X but excel will fill down formula till the last row plus another 3000 rows. I have tested this formula with different file and data set but I get the same error. Please can you advise.

Thanks,
R

```
Sheets("CJI Data").Select
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CJI Data")
LastRow = Sht.Range("X3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Range("Y3:AB3" & LastRow).FillDown
Range("A2:AB2").Select
```

Comment: `Range("Y3:AB" & LastRow).FillDown`

Comment: `CurrentRegion` will include any adjacent data, not just column X.  If you are only interested in Column X, then use `LastRow=Sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlup).Row`

Comment: Thanks Darrel H!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have `AB3`, just `AB`. The `Range` reference should include the first row and last row numbers. You're adding an additional 3 in front of the last row number, which results in the extra 3000 rows.

```
Range("Y3:AB" & LastRow).FillDown
```

Additionally, as pointed out by [@JohnColeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman), using `CurrentRegion.Rows` is not a foolproof method to get the last row. It might have unanticipated results if your data does not start in row 1.

Instead you can use `End(xlUp)` (also suggested by [@Darrell H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6466694/darrell-h)):

```
With Sht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlup).Row
End With
```

Comment: These both suggestions worked like a charm!! Thank you BigBen and Darrell!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Sub Test()
    Sheets("CJI Data").Select
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CJI Data")
    LastRow = Sht.Range("X1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("Y3:AB3" & LastRow).FillDown
    Range("A2:AB2").Select
End Sub
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Raul, I used Darrell H and Big Ben's suggestions and those resolved my issues.